# How long does it take for the atmosphere to mix?

Tags: meteorology, climate, atmospheric-circulation

If I release a say, one litre of gas, at a particular point on the planet, how soon, on average, would it take to be distributed evenly (mixed) across the entire earth's atmosphere?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by homologize? Do you mean mix entirely until evenly distributed?

Comment: Exactly that, evenly distributed - you've phrased it far better.  There seems to be far more data on the circulation of the ocean, but I want some estimate of this to include in a seminar, and I'd rather it be an informed estimate rather then my best guess.

Comment: @nemo183 I believe the word you want is "homogenize", rather than "homologize".

Comment: You are right. I'd couldn't decide between the two, and choose the wrong option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The time scale of interhemispheric tropospheric transport is in the order of one year (Chapter 4 of the book [Introduction to Atmospheric Chemistry](http://acmg.seas.harvard.edu/publications/jacobbook/index.html) written by Daniel J Jacob). This is not an exact answer to your question, but might be a fair enough number for the problem you have in mind.

Comment: Thank you, BHF. I've now read the chapter and I doubt there is a fuller explanation. It's exactly what I'd hoped for - always nice to have the maths to hand!

Comment: @nemo while this answer is sufficient, a fuller explanation exists, for example to include discussion of residence times and stratosphere mixixing.